# File upload more than 500mb in nodejs with express js http connection is giving error

Tags: node.js, express

I am getting this error when I try to upload a file which is greater than 500mb in nodejs with express js http connection:

```
RangeError : Array buffer allocation failed
```

I am able to upload small files like 10mb, 34mb.

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Are you using any modules for uploading or ? And please post the relevant code.

Comment: Appears to be a file upload buffer limit issue. Post your code so that we can sort out the bug. Posting just the error without proper info wouldn't help.